# How to handle query string Node Js AWS Lambda

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda to create a fetch API by passing a query parameter eg. vendorId, but in some case, I need whole data without passing the query parameter and in that case, my code is broken.
Let me know how I can handle the query parameter.

```
  var mysql=require('mysql'); //Require whatever connector you need.

  function getConnection()
   {
        var params={
           host     : 'myhostinfo',
           user     : 'myuser',
            password : 'mypwd',
           database : 'mydb'
    };

return mysql.createConnection(params);
}
      //This is your handler.
     exports.handler=function(event, context,callback)
    {

 //This is declared inside the handler: it is guaranteed to never be reused!.
   var connection=getConnection();
var fetchvendors="";


if(event.query.vendorid)
{   
    var vendorid=parseInt(event.query.vendorid);
    fetchvendors="SELECT v.*,c.vcategoryname FROM `tbl_vendors` v LEFT 
 OUTER JOIN tbl_demo_categories c ON v.vendorcatid=c.vcategoryid WHERE 
  v.vendorid="+vendorid;
}

else{
       fetchvendors="SELECT v.*,c.vcategoryname FROM `tbl_vendors` v LEFT 
OUTER JOIN tbl_demo_categories c ON v.vendorcatid=c.vcategoryid WHERE 
 status=1";
}
     connection.query(fetchvendors, function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) {
            connection.destroy();
             throw error;
          } else {
              // connected!
             callback(null, results);
             connection.end();
        }
     });
  }
```

here is the result

```
          Response:
        {
              "errorMessage": "RequestId: 42fd18b1-598c-4f7e-b93b- 
                b146777772b2 
            Process exited before completing request"
               }

          Request ID:
              "42fd18b1-598c-4f7e-b93b-b146777772b2"

             Function Logs:
            START RequestId: 42fd18b1-598c-4f7e-b93b-b146777772b2 Version: 
        $LATEST
             2019-04-04T10:48:34.959Z   42fd18b1-598c-4f7e-b93b- 
          b146777772b2  TypeError: Cannot read property 'vendorid' of 
                       undefined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should put pre-check for existence of object and its keys like this :

```
if(event && event.query && event.query.vendorid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sorry to say the problem is still the same.

Comment: after trying above solution now what error you are getting ? Please share error.

Comment: it solved my issue as there was something wrong in my code as in my string template I'm using param instead of a query. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 28):

If you are using API Gateway as the trigger to the lambda function, the query paramters are available at `event.queryStringParameters`. So you should be doing `event.queryStringParameters.vendorid` if vendorid is the GET param. Here's a full sample of API Gateway Proxy request to Lambda.

```
{
  "body": "eyP0ZXQ0IjoiYm9keSJ9",
  "resource": "/{proxy+}",
  "path": "/path/to/resource",
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "isBase64Encoded": true,
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "pathParameters": {
    "proxy": "/path/to/resource"
  },
  "stageVariables": {
    "baz": "qux"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
    "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
    "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
    "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
    "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
    "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
    "Host": "1234567890.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Custom User Agent String",
    "Via": "1.1 08f323deadbeefa7af34d5feb414ce27.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
    "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "cDehZQoZnx43VYQb9j2-naCh-9y396Uhbp027Y2JvkCPNLmGJHqlaA==",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2",
    "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
  },
  "requestContext": {
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "resourceId": "123456",
    "stage": "prod",
    "requestId": "c6af9ac6-7b61-11e6-9a41-93e8deadbeef",
    "requestTime": "09/Apr/2015:12:34:56 +0000",
    "requestTimeEpoch": 1428582896000,
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
      "accountId": null,
      "cognitoIdentityId": null,
      "caller": null,
      "accessKey": null,
      "sourceIp": "127.0.0.1",
      "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
      "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
      "userArn": null,
      "userAgent": "Custom User Agent String",
      "user": null
    },
    "path": "/prod/path/to/resource",
    "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "apiId": "1234567890",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this -

```
event.queryStringParameters.pincode
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this one is old but for me it worked when I used the following

```
event.queryStringParameters?.vendorid
```

Notice ?. operator because `vendorid` may not exist in the query string

Comment: The ?. operator is actually because event.queryStringParameters may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import middy from "@middy/core";
import httpEventNormalizer from "@middy/http-event-normalizer";

middy(handler).use([
  httpEventNormalizer()
])
```

then get query from **event.queryStringParameters?.queryParameterName**

middy will remove query parameters if their value is null from queryStringParameters